# Redactor default text after clicked outside of editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, default, redactor

when I load the redactor editor

```
$('#redactor").redactor();
```

it loads with the default text

> Click to add comment...

once clicked inside of the editor the text is removed.

Is there a way (simple, built in) to get back the text once clicked outside the editor and the editor is empty (nothing has been written in)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, had similar issue with another editor.

Note: I am using default redactors classes to target the elements.

1st part (html click function) checks if a click has been made in html document and then gathers the value of each redactor editor on page, if those values (after trimming) are null or '' it sets the inner html of redactor text box to its default value (got that from initialization)

2nd part checks if a click has been made in the editor and removes the anything inside if the value is null or has the inline element.

```
 $('html').click(function() {
    $.each($('.redactor_comment_textbox'), function() {
        var editorValue = $(this).html();
        if (editorValue.trim() == '') {
            $('.redactor_comment_textbox').html('<inline class="redactor_placeholder">Click to add a comment...</inline>');
        }
    });
});

$('.redactor_comment_textbox').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var editorValue = $(this).html();
    if (editorValue.trim() == '' || editorValue.substring(1,7)  == 'inline' ) {
        $(this).html(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a extra div above the div on which you are applying redactor editor, and on the click of that div just initialize your editor.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEYx7/8/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#upperDiv').click(function(){
       $.getScript("http://imperavi.com/js/redactor/redactor.js",function(){
             $('#article').redactor();   
      });

    });        
});



<div id = 'upperDiv' style='border: 1px red solid;height:300px;width:300px '>
    <div id="article">

    </div>
</div>
```